# Training yolo on custom detection and how to make a application?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tkinter, yolo

Once model is trained how it can be used in application, making small application for detection of human activities and the front-end is being made in **tkinter**?

Comment: you can use a model by using it

Comment: kindly guide me how can I do this? I am new to this field

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python then you can use something like [this](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/). It supports YOLO by default.